# How can I map specific names to IDs in JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Problem: I want to iterate through a specific set of name attributes and append those values to a specific ID.

I have a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qngzmuja/88/) that tries to read in a user input and the text to the right will get mirrored, respectively.

Currently I iterate through my specific name attributes. However, I now want to append to one respective text box to the right. It is appending to all four elements instead.

How can I map these elements?

```js
$('input[name^="text"]').on("change", function(e){
    var user_input = $(this).val();
  console.log(user_input);
  $('input[id^="id_text"').each(function() {
    let mirrored_value = $(this).val(user_input);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
    padding:10px;
}

input {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}
.mirror{
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.input{
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1> The right text box will mirror the left</h1>
<div class="input">
  <input type="text" name="text1" value=""><br>
  <input type="text" name="text2" value=""><br>
  <input type="text" name="text3" value=""><br>
  <input type="text" name="text4" value=""><br>
</div>

<div class="mirror">
  <input type="text" id="id_text1" value=""><br>
  <input type="text" id="id_text2" value=""><br>
  <input type="text" id="id_text3" value=""><br>
  <input type="text" id="id_text4" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: 10 karma points to the first person to find a duplicate question. This one probably has 50 of them, but I'm short on time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preferred method is using a data attribute that refers to the target element and refer to that. That way you don't have to worry about changing your javascript if you change your markup. Also the `input` event is the better option for text inputs.

```js
$('input[data-target]').on("input", function(e){
    $($(this).data("target")).val($(this).val());
});
```

```css
body {
    padding:10px;
}

input {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}
.mirror{
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.input{
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1> The right text box will mirror the left</h1>
<div class="input">
  <input data-target="#id_text1" type="text" name="text1" value=""><br>
  <input data-target="#id_text2" type="text" name="text2" value=""><br>
  <input data-target="#id_text3" type="text" name="text3" value=""><br>
  <input data-target="#id_text4" type="text" name="text4" value=""><br>
</div>

<div class="mirror">
  <input type="text" id="id_text1" value=""><br>
  <input type="text" id="id_text2" value=""><br>
  <input type="text" id="id_text3" value=""><br>
  <input type="text" id="id_text4" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: Even better would be to use `input[data-target]` as the selector to avoid the partial attribute selector :).

Answer (score 2):

Using closures and assuming the `<input>` element groups are in the same order:

```js
const $src = $('.input > input');
const $dst = $('.mirror > input');
$src.each((i,e) => {
  const $mirror = $dst.eq(i);
  $(e).on('change', e => {
    let user_input = $(e.currentTarget).val();
    console.log(user_input);
    $mirror.val(user_input);
  });
});
```

Comment: It's not so much the closure here as the fact that you're selecting destinations by index in the jQuery object array, right?

Comment: @isherwood Now that you ask, I'm not sure. I thought it was where I was pulling in `i` (now `$mirror`).

Answer (score 1):

I would use index if your markup is consistently reliable. No IDs or other attributes necessary.

```js
$('.input input').on("keyup", function(e){
    const idx = $(this).index();
    const val = $(this).val();
    $('.mirror input').eq(idx).val(val);
});
```

```css
.input, .mirror {display: inline-block; width: 45%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1> The right text box will mirror the left</h1>
<div class="input">
  <input type="text" name="text1" value="">
  <input type="text" name="text2" value="">
  <input type="text" name="text3" value="">
  <input type="text" name="text4" value="">
</div>

<div class="mirror">
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="">
</div>
```